# Watson Conversation - Oracle DB Integration

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, watson-conversation, watson

Good morning/afternoon all, I am trying to get Watson to return a response manually set from our Oracle Databases.

I am using async to sequentially access the database and return the response because the first problem I had was the DB query would not happen until after Watson had already returned a response. Async.waterfall fixes this.

My current problem: In the console I see everything logged correctly. The Database is queried, response.output.text is set correctly and then returned to Watson but no response ever appears in my chat.. If I set the response.output.text = "asdfa" before the async, asdfa is returned as expected.

I am at a loss trying to figure this out so I appreciate any and all help. Please let me know if any more information is required.

```
  // Send the input to the conversation service
conversation.message(payload, function (err, data) {
if (err) {
return res.status(err.code || 500).json(err);
}
return res.json(updateMessage(payload, data));
});
});

function updateMessage(input, response) {
 var responseText = null;
 if (!response.output) {
 response.output = {};
} else {
// checkNames check
if (response.output.nodes_visited[0] === 'slot_11_1519333387192' && response.entities[0].entity === 'confirm') {

  /* This code actually returns asdfa as a response from Watson.. */
  // response.output.text = "asdfa";
  // return response;
  async.waterfall([
      // this function queries the database
      // TODO: module out the Oracle connection parts once POC is completed
      function queryDB(callback) {
        console.log('Starting queryDB');
        var query = "SELECT column_name FROM table@prod WHERE column_id = '" + response.context.VSUID + "'";
        oracledb.getConnection('hr',
          function (err, connection) {
            var conn = oracleGetConnection(err, connection);
            conn.execute(query, {}, {
                outFormat: oracledb.OBJECT
              },
              function (err, result) {

                console.log('result from Oracle: ', result);
                // pass a null error and the result of the query

                callback(null, result.rows[0]);
              });
          });
      },
      // this function formats the result of the query
      // TODO: this should not be it's own function. This can happen at the same time the db gets the row 
      function formatName (arg1, callback) {
        console.log('this should happen after query..');
        console.log('arg1: ', arg1);

        var r = JSON.stringify(arg1);
        r = r.substring((r.indexOf(':') + 1) + 1, r.length - 2);
        console.log('Name is: ', r);
        // pass a null error and the formatted name
        callback(null, r);
      }
    ],
    // Final function to be ran after the two above have completed 
    function finalFunction (err, result) {
      if (err) {
        console.log('uh oh async err: ', err);
      } else {
        console.log('This is final Function');
        // set output text
        response.output.text = 'Is your name ' + result + '?';
        // response.context.dbResponse = 'Is your name ' + result + '?';
        // response.output.text = "asdfasdfasd";
        // console.log('This is the value of response\n\n', response);
        // var resp = returnResponse(input, response);
        response.context.dbResponse = response.output.text[0];
        return returnResponse(input, response);
        // return response;
      }
    });
    // response.output.text = "asdfa";
    console.log('This is response.output.text ', response.output.text);
    return response;
} else {
  //If no special if case to query the db just run Watson Conversation stock
  return returnResponse(input, response);
}
```

}
  }

Here is a sample console log.

```
This logs the Input from the user:
name 111111111
This logs the Response from Watson:
Is 111111111correct?
This logs the intent recognized, if any:
nameCheck
This logs the entity recognized, if any:
VSUID
This logs the text that is being returned to the user:  [ 'Is 111111111correct?'
]
Starting queryDB
Connected to database
result from Oracle:  { outBinds: undefined,
  rowsAffected: undefined,
  metaData: [ { name: 'TABLE_FIRST_NAME' } ],
  rows: [ [ 'Tyler' ], [ 'Tyler' ] ],
  resultSet: undefined }
this should happen after query..
arg1:  [ 'Tyler' ]
Name is:  "Tyler
This is final Function
This logs the Input from the user:
yes
This logs the Response from Watson:
Is your name "Tyler?
This logs the entity recognized, if any:
confirm
This logs the text that is being returned to the user:  Is your name "Tyler?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing code like the following will open you up to SQL injection vulnerabilities (and likely performance problems too):

```
var query = "SELECT column_name FROM table@prod WHERE column_id = '" + response.context.VSUID + "'";
```

Please read the [section of the documentation on bind variables](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/master/doc/api.md#bind).

On to your question...

You are treating `updateMessage` as though it is a synchronous function, but it is performing asynchronous work. A function that is performing asynchronous work will need an asynchronous API, such as Node.js style callbacks, Promises, or AsyncFunctions (async/await).

If you see line 73 of the code you supplied, you're "returning" the response object, but that is outside of the `async.waterfall` call. Even the return on line 67 will not work because of the asynchronous nature of Node.js.

Here's my latest attempt at describing how all of this works:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iAdeljxq_hs

You can access the slides and sample code here:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/quu7oxiug0gh6ua/Understanding%20Async%20Processing%20and%20Patterns%20in%20Node.js.zip?dl=0

In the sample code's **code > header-detail** directory, you'll see 5 different files that start with **header-detail-with-** followed but the name of a different API choice you could make. You will have to make a similar choice with your `updateMessage` API.

To run a test, use the **ddl.sql** file to create the target tables, then edit **db-config.js** as needed for your environment, and finally run `node test.js 1` from a terminal in that directory. You can change the number at the end to run a different test file.

Comment: Dan, you're amazing.

Comment: I have watched your video (a great overview btw, you killed it) and using your sample code rebuilt my async call. I come to the same problem sadly, since my database code depends on the 'response' object from Watson no matter how I implement it it seems that the response is being returned before the async call finishes. Here is the current code https://hastebin.com/zolesiforu.js . I would like to know logically how I should be approaching this.. thanks!

Comment: See if this helps: https://hastebin.com/hifoguhono.js I can't test it for syntax errors and such, but maybe it will give you the idea...

Comment: After some adaption of the code I have it working Dan!! You've been more help than the any support I have access to, which is just crazy. Thank you!! Thank you!! Thank you!!

Comment: Glad to hear it!